# Animation in Tower of Hanoi

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm doing a tower of hanoi in wpf. and I want it to have an animation on how to solve the puzzle with a given number of disk. but when I click the solve button it gives an error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in TowerOfHanoi.exe"

Heres the code:

```
    private void SolveTower(int diskNumber, Needle origin, Needle tempDest, Needle destination)
    {
        diskNumber = diskCounter;

        if (diskNumber == 1)
        {
            bgWorker.ReportProgress(0, new Solution(origin, destination));         // move this disk from needle1 to needle3
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        else
        {
            SolveTower(diskNumber - 1, origin, tempDest, destination);               // move n-1 disks from needle1 to needle2
            bgWorker.ReportProgress(0, new Solution(origin, destination));         // move the last disk from needle1 to needle3
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            SolveTower(diskNumber - 1, tempDest, destination, origin);               // move n-1 disks from needle2 to needle3
        }

    }
```

diskCounter is the number of disk a panel/needle has. I Just don't know how to rearrange it.

Here's the code for adding a disk in a panel/needle:

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        Rectangle disk = new Rectangle();
        disk.Height = 25;
        disk.Stroke = Brushes.BlueViolet;
        disk.RadiusX = 7;
        disk.RadiusY = 7;
        RadialGradientBrush rgBrush = new RadialGradientBrush();
        GradientStopCollection gsc = new GradientStopCollection();
        gsc.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.AliceBlue, 0));
        gsc.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.BlueViolet, 1));
        rgBrush.GradientStops = gsc;
        rgBrush.GradientOrigin = new Point(0.1, 0.9);
        rgBrush.RadiusX = 1;
        rgBrush.RadiusY = 1;
        disk.Fill = rgBrush;
        disk.MouseLeftButtonDown += disk_MouseLeftButtonDown;

        if (needle1.Children.Count < 10)
        {
            needle1.AddDisk(disk);

            btnSolve.IsEnabled = true;
            btnStart.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Maximum of 10 disks only");
        }

        diskCounter = needle1.Children.Count;
    }
```

Comment: This means that your algorithm is not working as expected.

Comment: What is the value of `diskNumber` when you call this the first time?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Do you not know why it is throwing a stack overflow exception or are you wanting to know how you can rearrange the program to avoid it or something else?

Comment: diskCounter is the number of disk a panel has.

Comment: Have you tried debugging this out of interest? as in stepped through the `SolveTower` method to see what is going on, whether the parameters make sense, etc. I think Patrick's answer probably hits the nail on the head as to why it is going wrong though. Perhaps you could comment on that to say if it has helped and if not why not.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if the `diskCounter` is less than 1. I don't really get the logic since you receive a parameter in your method (`diskNumber`) which you overwrite in the first line.

I think this is the cause of your problems. As a suggestion: check input parameters against the expected range, like this:

```
Debug.Assert(diskCounter > 0, "Disk counter should be more than 0");
```

Now, when you put this on the first line of your method you will see when debugging you receive a warning telling you something unexpected happened.

Comment: thanks for the help but I can't find Debug.Assert. I'm sorry, I'm just a newbie in this field. The details in the error that I've got was this one "Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state"

Comment: You should add `using System.Diagnostics;` on top of your cs file.

Comment: Any luck in resolving the issue? Need more help?